# Facebook php sdk - getUser() retururs ID on desktop, but 0 on mobile (generating infinite loop)

Tags: php, facebook, userid

here's my code to create a Facebook app and get user ID.

```
<?php

        $config = array(
            'appId' => 'XXX',
            'secret' => 'XXX',
            'cookie' => true
        );

        $facebook = new Facebook($config);

        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        if (!$user) {

            $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                'scope' => 'email,publish_actions,user_likes',
                'redirect_uri' => 'my_app_url'
            ));

            echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "';</script>");
        }

        else {
            //DO STUFF
        }

    ?>
```

The desktop works fine. On mobile I always get 0 as user ID (even after user accepts app), causing an infinite loop of redirect.

Anyone can help?

Thanks!
Alberto

Comment: Try to check your cookies - you should have cookie set by facebook to your domain, if you don't have it on mobile (like you have on desktop), you should look at cookies settings on mobile.

Comment: Also try destroying the session if not a user.

Comment: The cookie is not set on mobile, while it is on desktop.What can be the issue?

Comment: what is the domain name and canvas url u have specified on ur aap setting ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help someone.

The problem is that my piece of code is the first thing the app is doing, so I still don't have the Facebook cookie needed for auth.

My solution was to move the logic on the client side, using JS api.

```
var appId = 'XXX';
var canvasUrl = 'https://apps.facebook.com/XXX/';
var canvasUrlMobile = 'MY_SERVER_URL';
var scope = 'email,publish_actions,user_likes';

FB.init({
    appId                   : appId,
    status                  : true,
    xfbml                   : true,
    cookie                  : true,
    frictionlessRequests    : true
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {


    if (response.status === 'connected') {

        //DO STUFF
    }

    else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
    {
        // the user is logged in to Facebook, but has not authenticated app

        //MOBILE: for mobile I build the oauth url manually. Note that canvas url is different on mobile and desktop
        if ( detectmob() == true ) {
            location.href = "https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="+appId+"&redirect_uri="+canvasUrlMobile+"&scope="+scope;
        }

        //DESKTOP use FB.login
        else {

            FB.login(function(response) {

                if (response.authResponse) {

                    //be sure to load cookie
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        top.location.href = canvasUrl;
                    },500);
                }

                else {
                    //USER DIDN'T GIVE PERMISSION
                }
            },
            {scope: 'email,publish_actions,user_likes'});
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
        location.href = "https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="+appId+"&redirect_uri="+canvasUrlMobile+"&scope="+scope;
    }
});
```